# Export Highcharts on Serverside with php?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, server-side

I have following setup:

**First PHP File:** Gets data from mysql database, puts it into highchart, exports it to "export.highcharts.com" as png and posts the URL of the Image to PHP File number 2 via ajax post.

**Second PHP File:** Gets the "imagelink" from the Ajax Post from PHP File number 1 and connects then to twitter api to post a tweet including the image to the chart.

Now, this all works great as long as I execute the First PHP File in Browser.

I need to run this automated on "server-side" via cronjob. Now it doesnt work anymore because it contains ajax and ajax post, which does not get executed on server-side.

**Code of First PHP File:**

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Highcharts -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test";
    $db = "test";

    $connect = @mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

?>


<?php if ($connect && mysql_select_db($db, $connect)) : ?> <?php



        // Select twitterdata table
        $printMarketdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketdata ORDER BY volume24h DESC LIMIT 10") or die("MySQL Error! ".mysql_error());

        // Marketdata found
        if (mysql_num_rows($printMarketdata) > 0) {


        ?>


<script>
// Create the chart
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'TOP 10 Highest Trading Volume (24h)'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Trading Volume (24h)'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer', 
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '${point.y:,.0f}'
            },
        point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        location.href = 'https://example.com/' +
                            this.options.key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Trading Volume (24h)',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [

            <?php // output data of each row
            while ($marketdata = mysql_fetch_array($printMarketdata))
            {
                ?>

        {
            name: '<?php echo $marketdata['name'];?>',
            y: <?php echo $marketdata['volume24h'];?>,
            key: '<?php echo $marketdata['symbol'];?>'
        },

            <?php
            }
            ?>


        ]
    }],
                navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }

};



// URL to Highcharts export server
    var exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/';

    // POST parameter for Highcharts export server
    var object = {
        options: JSON.stringify(options),
        type: 'image/png',
        async: true
    };

    // Ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: exportUrl,
        data: object,
        success: function (data) {
            //Submit data from your server
             // Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'posttweet.php',//this your local file
                data: {'url' : exportUrl+data},
                success: function (data2) {
                    //Response from your server
                    //if your teste.php print response. echo "" or die("") ;
                    alert(data2);
                }
            });
        }
    });


</script>

<?php





        // No Data found
       } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

    ?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2>Database connection failed!</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Do you guys have any good code i can use (preferably PHP), so I can make highchart and export as image on server-side?**

Comment: To use highchart server-side, you will need a complete browser on your server... PHP won't do it, it's only use will be to call command lines and stuff...

Comment: Yup, so how to do it the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run AJAX from PHP, so you need to replace your javascript code with some PHP.

You can use cURL, or a cURL library like Guzzle to send requests to the other page, and API etc.

Have a look at the PHP docs for info on cURL:
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Roughly speaking, like this:

First PHP File: Gets data from mysql database, puts it into highchart, exports it to "export.highcharts.com" as png **and requires file2 and passes the result**

Second PHP File: Gets the "imagelink" **from the other PHP File** number 1 and connects then to twitter api to post a tweet including the image to the chart.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, so I need to make the whole highcharts to curl? Or only the export part?

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean... Is there any example how to use curl to export chart as an image? thanks! :)

Comment: You can send a request to the highcharts export server with the options to build a chart. It will return an image with the specified format. You can the API description here at the bottom of the page - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview